# How can substitute() operate on a whole buffer?

Tags: vimscript, buffers, substitute

In normal usage `:%s/A/B/g` is a simple way to substitute a pattern across the entire buffer. However the command mode implementation of `:substitute` is subject to many user configurable variables and as such linters rightfully complain about it's usage in scripts.

I'm trying to use `call substitute()` instead since this is [a documented best practice in scripts](https://google.github.io/styleguide/vimscriptguide.xml?showone=Fragile_commands#Fragile_commands). Using it against a string is easy, but [I can't figure out how to make it operate on a buffer](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc/issues/336). I seem to be able to to `call setline('1', substitute(getline('1'), 'A', 'B', ''))` to change one line at a time, but it doesn't work across a whole buffer.

What is the correct robust way to run a substitution across a whole buffer from a script or plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only problems I see with `:substitute` are:

- it messes a few registers
- we may have to be wary of the separator character used that'll need to be escaped
- its behaviour depends on `'magic`' option <del>(as well as `substitute()`'s one)</del>

If you really want to operate on the whole buffer without `:s`, you could also use the following oneliner (that'll be more efficient than any loop)

```
call setline(1, map(getline(1,'$'), {k,v -> substitute(v, 'PATTERN', 'REPLACEMENT', FLAGS)}))
```

Comment: Messing with registers is definitely one reason I DON'T want to use `:substitute`. I can work around the *magic*, *ignorecase*, and other unknown settings, but I don't want to either cause or rely on side effects, which `:s` does.

Comment: Thanks for the `map()` idea, but are you sure that's correct? Shouldn't the `setline()` be inside the map referencing `v` too?

Comment: `setline()` can take a list as well. And Yes I'm sure as I've tested it with: `call setline(1, map(getline(1,'$'), {k,v -> substitute(v, '\d\+', '\=(1+submatch(0))', 'g')}))`

Comment: Much better then mine :)

Comment: "more efficient than any loop"—I'd love to see timings. I'm not saying you're wrong, but I've read that vim's functional constructs are occasionally slower than the equivalent loops, and it depends a lot on the underlying machinery of each implementation here (as well as when and how the draws/updates happen)

Comment: I did a lot of measurements for the list functions of my lh-vim-lib library plugin. Every time `map()` and `filter()` were magnitude faster than raw loops. It was totalement independant of redrawing anything.

Comment: map() is indeed faster as raw loops. However, you might be running into memory limits here depending on the buffer content. For that reason `:s` might still be more efficient.

Comment: Could you give more detail about `mess a few registers` ? I didn't know this and google didn't show me anything about it.

Comment: @dedowsdi: It'll change the search register (`@/`) and history. And to be honest, I don't remember if the `@:` register will also be changed. Also we can use `:keeppattern`, `:keepjump`...

Comment: @LucHermitte Thanks, I thought we were talking about script here, those register changes doesn't happen if `:s` is executed in a script.

Comment: Thanks @dedowsdi. Nice to know. I've always been paranoid on the subject. Do you know how long it has been the case?

Comment: @LucHermitte  It's documented in `:h function-search-undo`, not sure how long it's  been there, `git log --grep 'function-search-undo'` give me nothing. It works only for functions obviously, script scope `/` and `s` still change search pattern.

Answer (score 2):

> since this is documented best-practice in scripts

Documented where?

In vimscript (in which plugins are written), every "statement" is an Ex command, you can do

```
function MyFunc() abort
  %substitute/pattern/repl/g
endfunction
```

or whatever it is you're trying to do. *This is in fact the simplest mechanism.* You can add modifiers (`keepjumps`, etc.) to the command, or build it up programmatically, or any of the usual things. But don't make this painful by trying to use a `substitute()` function—that works on a single string—on the entire buffer.

---

If you insist...

You could do a Schwarzian transform from list of lines to line, substitute, and reverse.

Or you could loop

```
for line in range(0, line('$'))
  call setline(line, substitute(getline(line), 'A', 'B', ''))
endfor
```

But, why?

---

See also [this Q&A](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5949/substitute-with-pure-vimscript-without-s?rq=1)

Comment: Documented in, for example, `vint` which cites [this guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/vimscriptguide.xml?showone=Fragile_commands#Fragile_commands). Also the vim help documentation also hints at the issues with `:substitute` in scripts.

Comment: Just because every statement is an ex command does not mean they are all safe to use in scripts. Many of them create side effects and many of them change behavior based on user configuration. The simplest mechanism is not what I want here, I specifically want the most robust that will not break if people have things setup weird and won't break their stuff. The ex command `:substitute` is known to have both issues (relies on user settings, and creates side effects).

Comment: @Caleb the side effects are avoidable, and the user settings which affect it are well documented. You can always save-restore those. Maxim even mentions controls for some of them which don’t need that—case and magic have pattern special items

Answer (score 0):

One way could be using regular `for` loop:

```
let idx = 1
for line in getbufline(bufnr('%'), 1, "$")
    call setline(idx, substitute(line, 'A', 'B', 'g'))
    let idx += 1
endfor
```

or

```
for line in range(0, line('$'))
  call setline(line, substitute(getline(line), 'A', 'B', 'g'))
endfor
```

which is pretty obvious.

Another one could be:

```
let buflines = getbufline(bufnr('%'), 1, "$")
%delete _
call append(0, map(buflines, {_, line -> substitute(line, 'A', 'B', 'g')}))
$delete _
```

It takes all current buffer lines, then deletes whole buffer and appends transformed by map saved buffer lines.
With `append` you going to have additional newline at the end, so the last line deletes it.

There probably more ways to do it, not sure.

But!

I would still go with regular `%s//` command. Remember you can set it up the way you like using `:execute` command:

```
let pattern = 'A'
let sub = 'B'
execute "%s/" . pattern . "/" . sub . "/g"
```

Note, instead of dot concatenation ppl suggest using `printf`.

Comment: Using `:execute %s` does not solve the problem of not being in control of the `ignorecase`, `smartcase`, `cpoptions`, `magic` or other options that affect `:substitute`.

Comment: magic and ignorecase and smartcase is easy, just use `:%s/\m\cA/B/g`